# Segmentation Fault (Core Dump) Happen and NOT Happen on 2 Different Distro of Linux

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm a newbie to Linux OS, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit)  to do a C++ project. Unluckily, when my teacher gave me a C++ code, I got a Segmentation Fault (core dump) when I ran it on my Ubuntu, but when I asked my friend to run it on his Elementary OS (32 bit) - another distro of Linux, the code worked really well. So I want to ask some questions:

1. Is it possible a program runs well on a 32-bit version, but cannot run on a 64-bit one (in my case, Core Dump)?
2. My computer is 64-bit machine, can I install a 32-bit version of Ubuntu?
3. Should I try Ubuntu 15 to see if it gets the same error (Core Dump)?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. yes. 3. without more information I don't think it would help. I removed your debian question since it is entirely unrelated to the rest of your post  here.

Comment: Please: 1 question per topic. #3 is not a question we can answer. Debian related question go on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ 4. can not be answered; just install it and see for yourself ;-) . If I was you I would reword this question to focus on the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

The best bet is to probably learn how to debug your code using gdb.  Build your code with the -g flag (to enable debug symbols) and then run in side gdb, e.g.

```
gdb ./nameofyourprogram
```

when the segmentation fault occurs, type "where" and you will see where it crashes.  Learning to debug code is just as important as learning to code.  it may be also a good idea to get up to speed with the debugger using a online [getting started guide](https://beej.us/guide/bggdb/).